# Gawk and systime()

Tags: awk

This command calculates the number of seconds:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ "date -d \"12:50:57\" +%s" | getline; print }' 
1352893857
```

How to do the same with the "strftime" and "systime ()" ?:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print strftime("12:50:57", systime())}' 
12:50:57
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The `strftime()` function will only format a specified timestamp and the `systime()` function will only return the current timestamp. I think you're thinking about the `mktime()` function, but you'd need to know the year, month, day:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print mktime("2012 11 14 12 50 57") }'
```

Results:

```
1352861457
```

You can read more about `GNU awk`'s time functions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html). HTH.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d 12 50 57"))}'
1352919057
$ awk 'BEGIN{print mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d " gensub(/:/," ","g","12:50:57")))}'
1352919057
```